# what is wrong with this code? i am unable to get 'welcome' output out of this.. using codeblocks.. im a beginner

Tags: c, codeblocks

Trying to get the welcome output after using 'abcd' as username and '1234' as password.

```
int main()

{

char username[5];
int password;

printf("username: \t");
scanf("%s", username); 

printf("password: \t");
scanf(" %d", &password);

(( username=='abcd')&&(password==1234)?printf("\nwelcome"):printf("\nlogin failed")); 

}
```

Comment: use `strcmp()` and please search before you post.

Comment: Please put the `\n` newline at the end of the `printf` output, not the beginning, is the typical way to do it.

Comment: And don't use theconditional operator here. Use the conditional statement (`if`).

Answer (score 0):

Use `strcmp(username, "abcd") == 0` instead of `username=='abcd'`

Comment: it is crashing when using    (strcmp(username,'abcd') == 0)

Comment: @ayush002 Then read the answer again.

Comment: problem solved thanks!